# Creating a list widget for the dashboard

Tags: plotly, bokeh, plotly-dash, plotly-python, ipywidgets

In many of the desktop application libraries there is a specific widget for showing a list of items. For example in `Qt` it is called `QListWidget`.  Users can perform variety of operations on such widgets. For instance, they can rename, remove, move up/down, etc., different elements.

[image]

I would like to have such a widget in the dashboard that I am creating using Dash. It is a photo filtering dashboard that a user uploads his/her photo and then chooses a series of filters from the list widget (that I hope to find a way to implement it) and then those filters will be applied on the photo based on the selection order. So far, I could not find any thing even close to such a widget in Plotly or Dash.

I am developing this dashboard using Dash but I am also open to other python frameworks or libraries.

Comment: There's no native widget for this in `ipywidgets`, but could be achieved through a simple combination of `ipywidgets.Select`/`ipywidgets.SelectMultiple` and `ipywidgets.Button`.